# Wordpress - how to add a code snippet to <head> of each page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to add some code to the head of each page that loads using a plugin that I build. What is the proper hook for this and the proper way of doing it? Thanks a lot

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add JS code, use the [wp_enqueue_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function - put your call in a function which gets added to the filter 'wp_enqueue_scripts'.

To add HTML, write a function to render whatever code you need and put it onto the [wp_head](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) filter. As in `add_action('wp_head', 'your_function');`

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you. I did try your method and it doesnt print out my code to the head tag. I was reading about `wp_head` and noticed that it says `This hook is theme-dependent which means that it is up to the author of each WordPress theme to include it. It may not be available on all themes, so you should take this into account when using it.` I am not seeing any error messages either. Any help?

Comment: wp_head() does get called in the theme btw

Comment: maybe its getting called after the wp_head() function runs. Can anyone recommend me a solution? I can't add anything to functions.php file. Everything has to be done using the plugin

Answer (score 5):

For those looking for a sample code, here it is:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'YOUR_SCRIPT_IN_HEAD_FUNCTION' );     
function YOUR_SCRIPT_IN_HEAD_FUNCTION() {
    echo '<script>
        // some code
    </script>';
}
```